# Type' not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'. React Typescript App

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Estaba desarrollando una `App` en `React` con `Typescript`, en la que implemento `Firebase` como servicio de `Login` de usuarios.

El error que me surje es el siguiente, y seguramente es por desconocimiento del framework de `React`, ya que se trata de un problema al definir el `html` del Componente `SignIn`:

Error:

```
Type '{ type: string; name: string; value: string; onChange: (e: any) => void; placeholder: string; label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'type' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)
```

El error hace mención al archivo `SigIn.tsx` file, al intentar definir el `html` del componente:

SignIn.tsx:

```
import React, { FC, useState, FormEvent, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import Input from '../UI/Input';
import Button from '../UI/Button';
import Message from '../UI/Message';
import { signin, setError } from '../../store/actions/authActions';
import { RootState } from '../../store';

const SignIn: FC = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { error } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if(error) {
        dispatch(setError(''));
      }
    }
  }, [error, dispatch]);

  const submitHandler = (e: FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(error) {
      dispatch(setError(''));
    }
    setLoading(true);
    dispatch(signin({ email, password }, () => setLoading(false)));
  }

  return(
    <section className="section">
      <div className="container">
        <h2 className="has-text-centered is-size-2 mb-3">Sign In</h2>
        <form className="form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          {error && <Message type="danger" msg={error} />}
          <Input 
            type="email"     //Here is where error rise.
            name="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.currentTarget.value)}
            placeholder="Email address"
            label="Email address"
          />
          <Input 
            type="password"`     //Here is where error rise.
            name="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.currentTarget.value)}
            placeholder="Password"
            label="Password"
          />
          <p><Link to="/forgot-password">Forgot password ?</Link> </p>  // In this line rise the error too.
          <Button text={loading ? "Loading..." : "Sign In"} className="is-primary is-fullwidth mt-5" disabled={loading} />
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default SignIn;
```

Como digo, el error se produce al definir los atributos de los `Input`, y del `Link`, y seguramente sea un problema con `React`.

Si pueden ayudar, muchas gracias de ante mano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta definir bien os tipos de las funciones que pasas al onChange y al onSubmit... quizás no resuelva todo el problema, pero seguro te deja más cerca de la solución.

Te dejo unos ejemplos.

```
const handleChangeName : React.ChangeEventHandler = (e : 
React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) : void  => {
    e.preventDefault()
    //console.log(e.target.value, 'handle name');
    setvalueName(e.target.value)
}

const handleSubmit: 
React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = (
e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>
 ): void => {
e.preventDefault()
 // rest of  code
 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario! Probare a implementarlo.